# The function $x\mapsto\int_0^1k(x,y)f(y)\mathrm{d}y$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k\in C([0,1]\times[0,1])$ be given. I would like to show that $\forall f\in C[0,1]$, the function $x\mapsto\int_0^1k(x,y)f(y)\mathrm{d}y$ is continuous. I tried to prove by uniform continuity of $k$, but in vain. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Kf(x) :=\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)d\, y $, then
\begin{eqnarray}
|Kf(x) - Kf(z)| &=& \left|\int_0^1 \left(k(x,y)-k(z,y)\right) f(y)d\, y \right| \\
&\le& \int_0^1 |k(x,y)-k(z,y)||f(y)|dy
\end{eqnarray}
Now if $\varepsilon >0 $ choose $\delta >0 $ such that $|x-z| < \delta $ implies $|k(x,y)-k(z,y)| < \frac{1}{||f||_{C^0} + 1 }\varepsilon$. Note that this can be done independently of $y$, since $k$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $[0,1]\times[0 ,1]$.

Then the right hand side of the inequality is less than $\varepsilon \times$ the volumue of the interval $[0,1]$ (which is $=1$), so $< \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. In $|k(x,y)-k(z,y)| < \frac{1}{||f||_{C^0} + 1 }\varepsilon$, are you considering the function $k(\cdot,y)$ with $y$ fixed?

Comment: @Steve he is using that $k$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $[0, 1]^2.$ Recall that Heine-Cantor theorem asserts that a continuous function will be uniformly continuous on every compact subset of its domain.